# Read Excel and insert to Access Database using java

Tags: java, ms-access, apache-poi

I am new to Java World, Using Apache Poi I am able to read the Student Excel sheet and display the output in the console(with col header ie Name, Roll no, Address, Location.)

```
 String a = "E:/Data.xls";
    List sheetData = new ArrayList();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream(a);

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            List data = new ArrayList();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                data.add(cell);
            }

            sheetData.add(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
    showExelData(sheetData);
}

private static void showExelData(List sheetData) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
        List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) list.get(j);
            //headers display
            System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());

            if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
}
```

SO My issue is i need to fetch data from excel and need to insert to my Access "Student" table. I knw the DB connection function. How can i fetch and insert exact info to the table with ignoring col headers. Any Suggestions Plz.
Thnks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick and dirty and use once solution, I would build an SQL insert statement based on the values you read from the excel sheet.  You can easily modify the showExelData method above to build and sent an insert sql statement to the database. [Look here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-insert-a-record/) for guidance

For a more permanent solution you need to use an ORM like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) .  Here's a link for a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6i12sNUO0aY